# IIS 7 - Can't send email until Print Spooler service restarted

Tags: email, iis, asp-classic, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

WEB ENVIRONMENT
IIS 7.5, Windows 2008 R2, Classic ASP

So every couple of days or weeks (its totally random) one of our webservers will stop sending emails and report an error code of "80040211", which is a generic "Could not send email" message. I'm using a "CDO.Message" object to do handle sending mail, and mail is being sent on a separate, in house SMTP server. Once the error occurs, I restart the "print spooler" service on that server, it can send mail immediately.

This happens on our Production and Development servers. All servers are running IIS 7.5, Windows 2008 R2, and we use Classic ASP.

Does anyone have an idea of why the Printer Spooler service would stop email from being sent? and once its restarted, email works again?

Update: here's the code I'm using in case anyone wants it for reference:

```
SET mail = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

mail.To         = "myWorkEmail@myjob.com"
mail.From       = "myWorkEmail@myjob.com"
mail.Subject    = "Test subject"
mail.HTMLBody   = "Test email"



mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing")=2
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver")="smtp" 'this is the name of the SMTP server, its name is literally "smtp"
mail.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport")=25 
mail.Configuration.Fields.Update
ON ERROR RESUME NEXT
mail.Send
ON ERROR GOTO 0

SET mail = NOTHING
```